# XPages categorized view expandlevel

Tags: view, xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to present a categorized view in a Lotus Domino XPage with all categories collapsed initially. I have successfully used page.xsp?expandLevel=1 in the URL, as well as setting the property ExpandLevel to 1 in the view panel.

The problem is, when I click on any category to expand it, it does not open on the first click. Instead, it turns the twistie as though the category was expanded, but displays nothing. If I click again, it closes the twistie. If I click a third time, it correctly opens the category.

This behavior is consistent, I have tried it on several views, and tried opening several categories. I have tried Chrome and IE. Am I the only one to see this, or just the only one who cares?

I am using the latest code, 8.5.3FP3

Anyone know a work-around or other method of doing this?

Comment: How do you use the URL parameter of `expandLevel` in your view? Some code on that could be helpful.

Comment: The code is as I show above in the URL, page.xsp?expandLevel=1 or else in the view All Properties, data\data\expandLevel is set to 1

Comment: what control do you use to show view data?

Comment: I am using a basic view panel

Comment: Do you have any JS in onclick events etc? Some code samples would help answering the question...

Comment: Check for any client and server side JS errors when it does not work.

Comment: No javascript errors in Firebug, and nothing in the server log. I have absolutely no additional code, simply using the stock Domino XPage  view control on a categorized view. Does nobody else see this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing the same problem.  I seem to only see the problem the first time I click on the category to expand - I would have to click it twice.  Subsequent clicking on a category will work as long as the page with the view panel remains open.   Based on my particular experience, this is the work-around I have come up with:

I continue to use the `expandLevel="1"` in the view panel.

```
<xp:dominoView var="vwSecurityType" viewName="bySecurityType" expandLevel="1">
</xp:dominoView>
```

In the "after page load" event, I add this code:

```
var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
var model:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel = viewPanel.getDataModel();
var container:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer = model.getDominoViewDataContainer();
container.expand("0");
```

I hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that has been reported to the code XPages Dev team as an issue before. 
However without seeing what your underlying view data sources look like I'm guessing that you have multiple subcategories and\or responses to responses in the View. Here you might see a problem or better described a delay in the view refreshing after expanding one row of a view where you have all rows collapsed - expandLevel=1 
This is something that has been addressed in 9.0 (though not in the Beta) and you should see a huge improvement in this area. 
That is of course if it is what the underlying behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Nope, no response to response, one categorized column. This is really easy to reproduce, please try it yourself if you do not believe me. I guess I'll see what 9.0 brings, I am really hoping for a lot of loose ends to be tied up in XPages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a clear bug in 8.5.3 with expandLevel=1 and as @John said is really easy to reproduce. I had to use this function (similar to @bj but without xp:dominoView):

```
function collapseExpandAll(id, bColapse){
    var viewPanel = getComponent(id);
    var model:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel = viewPanel.getDataModel();
    var container:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer = model.getDominoViewDataContainer();
    if(true === bColapse){
        container.collapseAll();    
    }else{
        container.expandAll()    
    }        
}
```

and call

```
collapseExpandAll("viewPanel1", true)
```

to collapse all and

```
colapseExpandAll("viewPanel1", false)
```

to expand all.